# how to reload datatable inside a modal

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a datatable inside my modal, in that madal, there's a form in it and when the submit button is click, I want the datatable to refresh and add the new data. Please is it possible, if it is, please show me how... Thanks

Comment: @RyanWilson thanks for your guide, it works perfect now.... the table refreshes when submit button is clicked... Thanks once again... Can you put your comment as answer so I will mark it?

Comment: Added as an answer per your request. I'm glad I was able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ajax` to post the data to the server, on the `ajax success callback function` clear the datatable from your modal and re-render the datatable from the data returned from your `ajax post`, documentation on ajax post:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, if this doesn't work please share the working demo so we can help you out.

```
$("#popup").on("shown.bs.modal", function(e) {
  $("#example")
    .DataTable()
    .columns.adjust()
    .responsive.recalc();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have rectify my issue with @RyanWilson guide... Thanks once again

Comment: Good to hear that :)